# Should I free memory allocated by malloc in case it would return a null pointer?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

Let’s say I have a pointer and allocate some memory for it. In case `malloc` would return a null pointer for whatever reasons, is it considered good practice to free it? Does it change something in this case? Is a check for `malloc` returning a null pointer even necessary?

```
char *some_function()
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        free(ptr);
        return NULL;
    }
    //some operations with the pointer
}
```

Comment: `free(NULL)` does nothing. (That's guaranteed by the standard.) So you can do it if you want to, but there's no point. If `malloc` returned `NULL`, no memory was allocated so there is nothing to free.

Comment: a check for NULL return is certainly needed. You called malloc to get some memory *so that you could store something in it*, if it returned NULL trying to store something is going to crash

Comment: FYI, `NULL` is a macro whose replacement is null pointer constant (which, in spite of its name, might not be a pointer). What `malloc` returns, if it failed to allocate space, is a null pointer. There are technical differences that you might never encounter, and I expect there is a Stack Overflow question on it somewhere, but what you can take away from this is that you should just call a null pointer a “null pointer”, not “`NULL`”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Do you mean the way I phrased my question or that I should make it a null pointer specifically in my code instead of NULL macro? Like (void *)0 or an uninitialized pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A check for `malloc` returning `NULL` is definitely necessary, since you cannot use `NULL` as a pointer to memory.

On the other hand, `free(NULL)` does nothing. (That's guaranteed by the standard.) So you can do that if you want to, but there's absolutely no point. If `malloc` returned `NULL`, no memory was allocated so there is nothing to free.

The point of `free(NULL)` being legal (and doing nothing) is that it lets you call `free` on any pointer returned by `malloc`, which simplifies resource freeing:

```
void do_something(unsigned n) {
    int* data = malloc(n * sizeof(*data));
    if (data) {
        // Do something
    }
    else {
        sprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate temporary vector of %ud ints\n", n);
    }
    free(data);
}
```